# Invalid command WSGIDaemonProcess Deploy Django application on CentOS 6.7

Tags: python, django, apache, centos6

I am using **Django 1.8** on **CentOS 6.7** with **Apache** Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix).

I have followed the steps in [How To Serve Django Applications with Apache and mod_wsgi on CentOS 7.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-centos-7) 
But at last step when I start the **Apache** server with command : `service httpd start` instead of `systemctl start httpd` beacuse  I have Centos 6.7 not CentOS 7 according to tutorial.

It is giving the following error:

```
Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 10 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/django.conf:
Invalid command 'WSGIDaemonProcess', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module ot included in the server configuration
```

you can check the django.conf here:

```
Alias /static /home/ftpispy/ispy/static
<Directory /home/ftpispy/ispy/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /home/ftpispy/ispy/ispy>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
WSGIDaemonProcess ispy python-path=/home/ftpispy/ispy:/home/ftpispy/ispy/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup ispy
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ftpispy/ispy/ispy/wsgi.py
```

Thanks in advance.Please suggest any other option  to deploy on **CentOS 6.7** with **djnago 1.8**.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

make sure you have wsgi package installed, by running

```
sudo a2enmod wsgi
```

if its not installed, execute below commands to install

for python2

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

for python3

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

Comment: How does this have 8 upvotes? original question was about CentOS, this answer suggests using apt-get?!

Comment: I searched for the same issue for Ubuntu and I landed on this page. I found the solution later, I added it here if in case someone else lands on the same page like me.

Comment: Hi, I'm getting "No package libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 available", Help me out to fix this.

Comment: what is the full command you are using to install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3  ??

try updating your apt-get,   "sudo apt-get update"  and then try installing.

Comment: The question was for CentOS not for ubuntu, so the apt commands wont work..

Comment: how does this work for aws ec2. mod-wsgi- they provide is not for python3? i used pip3 to install mod_wsgi. now i cannot start apache

Answer (score 16):

Right way to install `mod_wsgi` today in 2020 (source: https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/233)

**I.** Uninstall `libapache2-mod-wsgi`

```
sudo apt-get remove libapache2-mod-wsgi

sudo apt-get remove libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

**II.** Use pip to install `mod_wsgi`

```
pip install mod_wsgi
```

If it is already installed, update it:

```
pip uninstall mod_wsgi
pip install mod_wsgi
```

**III.** After that,  `mod_wsgi-express` command must be available. Use it with

```
mod_wsgi-express module-config
```

**IV.** Grab its output, this is what you need to tell Apache where to find your new `mod_wsgi` version.
**V.** Update `wsgi.load` file

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi.load
```

remove any lines of `wsgi.load` And past the output from **IV**

**VI.** Ensure `mod_wsgi` is enabled:

```
sudo a2enmod wsgi
```

**VII.** Restart your apache service

```
systemctl reload apache2
```

Comment: tks so much dude... good vibes fo you ;)

Answer (score 6):

The `mod_wsgi` module should be enabled for `Apache`. Make sure you have symlinks setup in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/` pointing to `wsgi.conf` and `wsgi.load` in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/`.

On a side note, check out the latest generation of [`mod_wsgi`](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi), it provides a convenient way to launch `wsgi` applications using a simple tool `mod_wsgi-express` (without the hassle of setting up an `httpd` configuration).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same Problem. Actually I did not load the mod_wsgi module in httpd.conf file. After spending many hours I solved by adding

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

in to the httpd.conf file. Then there is no more error.

Comment: Thank you this worked for me on Amazon Linux 2 EC2

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error

> Invalid command 'WSGIDeamonProcess', perhaps misspelled or defined by
>   a module not included in the server configuration

Because forgot to write "**/**" before path

> WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www...

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the correct version of mod_wsgi is installed in CentOS.  The mod_wsgi that comes with the yum repo is compiled based on (iirc) python 2.6.  You need mod_wsgi compiled using python 2.7.

I think [1] might help you with it, though it mentions CentOS 5/6 using python 2.4 (CentOS 6.7 uses python 2.6 as the basis).

[1] - https://blog.webhostpython.com/2015/01/12/how-to-install-python-2-7-with-mod_wsgi-on-a-centos-6-vps-or-server-with-cpanel/