# `NameError: name 'TypeError' is not defined` in Apache (mod_wsgi)

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi, python-3.8, asgi

### Install Version

#### Apache

- apr-1.6.5
- apr-util-1.6.1
- httpd-2.4.7
- mod_wsgi-4.6.8
- pcre-8.32

#### Python

- 3.8.5

#### Django

- 3.1.2

#### Apache http.conf

```sh
Listen 3600
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
<VirtualHost *:3600>
    WSGIDaemonProcess project_name display-name=project_name
    WSGIScriptAlias / /data/project_name/config/wsgi.py  process-group=api application-group=api
    ServerName project_name
    <Directory /data/project_name/config>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

### Error log

```sh
Exception ignored in: <function Local.__del__ at 0x7fd675a70a60>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/venv/api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asgiref/local.py", line 96, in __del__
NameError: name 'TypeError' is not defined
```

The above error log is coming out over and over and over again.
I don't know why there is an asgi related error when I don't use asgi.

Comment: I observe this, too, since today. `TypeError` is a Python built-in. Possibly, this is a race while the Python interpreter is shutting down?

Comment: @TorstenBronger  Hi, No error occurred if option WSGIDaemonProcess was not used.
Is there any other solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, it was a “Heisenbug” for me – while troubleshooting it, it went away for other reasons.

Comment: Same here after upgrading `python3-distupgrade`. Maybe this package update causes the issue?

Comment: How to fix it? Upgrading `python3-distupgrade` didn't help.

Comment: Did you solve this error? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after a system update

After the update, the module wsgi was not enabled anymore. Hence enabling it solved the problem

In Ubuntu I executed

```
sudo a2enmod wsgi
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33320889/invalid-command-wsgidaemonprocess-deploy-django-application-on-centos-6-7#47399305) has some related information

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same similar things in my logs, only during apache shutdown (and thus restart). It is probably background threads still running while the python interpreter is being shut down, as answered by @GrahamDumpleton in a similar-style question (with different errors) several years ago. See [NameError: name 'hasattr' is not defined - Python3.6, Django1.11, Ubuntu16-17, Apache2.4, mod_wsgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44939556/nameerror-name-hasattr-is-not-defined-python3-6-django1-11-ubuntu16-17-a)